# losting images with .docx to .zip

Tags: zip, docx

If I change the extension from docx to zip or save document as web-page I lose some images in foler /media .
Most of the images are preserved in order, but some were lost

What kind of problem could happen ?

Answer (score 0):

File had equals pictures, that user insert not from file, but copy from another place in Microsoft Word. In that case MW don't insert all of them in /meadia directory.